# Aroldis Chapman's Speed

Tags: baseball, pitching

I know that he has the record for the fastest pitch ever, but there is an hilarious stat that I found (but now cannot find again) once showing the 20 or so fastest pitches since 2000.  I think Chapman had all but 2.

Has there ever been another pitcher who was this much ahead of the rest of the league?  In other words, has there been a pitcher who's fastball was so consistently much faster than anyone else's?

Comment: The 2nd part of your question isn't really answerable.  There are plenty of closers who don't throw 100 mph or more and are plenty good.(Not really sure what Matt Anderson or Steve Dalowski have to do with the question as neither were really closers, unless you're simply referring to their speed).  Usually if a pitcher doesn't have top notch speed they rely on finesse, and pitch placement to get outs, instead of relying on the "blew by you" kind of speed that Chap has.

Comment: Agreed - I've edited out the second part of the question, leaving just the objective first part.

Comment: Ok.  I get it.  Probably didn't phrase it well

Comment: And technically Nolan Ryan in 1974:  The pitch in question happened on August 20, 1974 when Ryan played for the California Angels. It was recorded at 100.9 mph at 10 feet from the plate. This, when averaged out to today’s standard 50 feet from the plate, is best estimated at the incredible number of **108.1 mph**

Answer (score 1):

During the 2018 MLB season, Jordan Hicks had the two fastest pitches recorded at 105.1 and 105.0 mph. Outside of several Chapman pitches and two pitches by Tayron Guerrero, Jordan Hicks dominated [the first page of results](http://m.mlb.com/statcast/leaderboard#pitch-velo,r,2018) of MLB Statcast's list of fastest pitches.

[image: 2018 Statcast Fastest Pitches]

Comment: Poor Odubel Herrera.  He seems over-represented on here.  I think the dominance of Chapman and now Hicks may represent an upward trend.  As player conditioning gets better, these numbers should continue to improve (slightly)